# Simple Regex String Manipulation

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

Just a simple question. I am wondering how to write a regex expression for the phrase     'Ste 5800 Bldg 10 Ste A'.

I would like it to handle both the numeric values and the letter values after the wordphrase. I am just having trouble doing that. I have '\w+\s\d+, but i do not know how to include the letter values.

The end result should be 'Ste 5800','Bldg 10','Ste A'.

Comment: Can you say which letters are fixed ?

Comment: I think this will answer it. I want to only capture multiple digits and singular letters such that I want the regex to capture 'Ste A' but not "Ste Aspect". Is that good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yB8tB7)**

Try this:

```
(\w+) (\d+|[a-zA-Z])\b
```

Comment: It does not match the strings he wants

Comment: yup, I forgot the parenthesis.

Comment: guys I have another question lol, would you want me to ask here on the comments or on a new question all together?

Comment: @user3683871 New question please :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923059/string-manipulation-with-regular-expression-specifically-or-statements

Comment: @user3683871 you can check my answer on your question page :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job.

'Ste 5800','Bldg 10','Ste A'.

```
\w+\s[\d\w]+
```

If you want to search for 'Ste A' but not 'Ste Aspect'

```
\b\w+\s\d+|\b\w+\s\w\b
```

Comment: Thanks! and what if i wanted to only capture multiple digits and singular letters such that I want the regex to capture 'Ste A' but not "Ste Aspect"?

Comment: are there allways ' or " at the end or spaces?