# String Manipulation with Regular Expression specifically or statements

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I am trying to parse out certain strings from a phrase. This is the phrase:
'1st Floor 2nd Floor 3rd Floor 4th Floor'
The end phrase should be:
'1st Floor','2nd Floor','3rd Floor','4th Floor'

I am having trouble getting the '1st','2nd','3rd','4th' parts of the regex. I know I can do a less-intuitive version by using 4 different or statements but I am wondering if I can do it with one.

'\dst\s\w+|\dnd\s\w+|\drd\s\w+|\dth\s\w+'  - this is the long way that i am trying to shorten

Is there anyway to combine the st,nd,rd,and th into one statement without repeating the formatting after?
Thanks.

Comment: try this \d+[a-zA-Z]{2}\s\w+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/mO6iD1)**

Here's the regex:

```
(\d+(st|nd|rd|th)) \w+\b
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can combine st, nd, rd, and th into one statement, but it looks like you are trying to get a list out of this regex. Why not try [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) like this?

```
>>> import re
>>> t = '1st Floor 2nd Floor 3rd Floor 4th Floor'
>>> re.split(r'(?<=Floor)\s+', t)
['1st Floor', '2nd Floor', '3rd Floor', '4th Floor']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
import re
s = '1st Floor 2nd Floor 3rd Floor 4th Floor'
s2 = re.findall(r'\w+ Floor', s)
```